# Empty Fragment list with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

For a start I'm trying to populate a `FrgamentList` with random data but the list is always empty.
Also tried switching to a fragment with `ListView` but it didn't work too.
Here is my project code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="as400samplecode.com.myapplication.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Location:

```
public class Location {
    public String locName;
    public int locImage;

    public Location(String locName, int locImage) {
        this.locName = locName;
        this.locImage = locImage;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

MyListFragment:

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
        locations.add(new Location("bla5", R.drawable.eiffel));
        locations.add(new Location("bla6", R.drawable.eiffel));

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), locations);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter:

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private List<Location> locations;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<Location> locations) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder; // to reference the child views for later actions

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, null);
            // cache view fields into the holder
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeImage);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeName);

            holder.txtTitle.setText(locations.get(position).locName);
            //holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(locations.get(position).locImage);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(locations.get(position).locImage);

            // associate the holder with the view for later lookup
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Any idea what can it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder; // to reference the child views for later actions

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, null);
        // cache view fields into the holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeImage);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeName);

        holder.txtTitle.setText(locations.get(position).locName);
        //holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(locations.get(position).locImage);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(locations.get(position).locImage);

        // associate the holder with the view for later lookup
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
  // although you have added a ViewHolder it is not used once your view is generated
 // you are just instantiating convertView if it is null and not doing anything after that   

    return v;
}
```

when your `convertView` is not null add a else condition and retrieve the `ViewHolder` instance which you added

```
else {
  holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}
 // now you would be feeding information to your `ImageView` and `TextView`

holder.txtTitle.setText(locations.get(position).locName);
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(locations.get(position).locImage);
```

Comment: It doesn't help. 
Something very strange happens, when I'm debugging I see that the app never reaches that method, is it normal?

Comment: no, it is not normal, look at few example of custom listview, how the custom adapter is working, try to put Log where ever you think is necessary to check the progress of code

Answer (score 0):

Had to override the get `getCount()` method like that:

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return locations != null ? locations.size() : 0;
}
```